# Launch App through SMS (URI-Association)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to launch an App using a pre-registered URI through SMS? I successfully tested launching Apps through links on websites (e.g. myapp:param=test in the href of a link) but had no luck concerning SMS.

Is there any way to launch own Apps out of Short Messages?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Are you wanting to be able to launch the App when a certain SMS message is received, or launch the App when you send a certain SMS message?

Comment: I want to launch the App when a certain SMS message is received. I doesn't even have to be automatic, a Link in the SMS that (when clicked on) launches my App would suffice completely.

Comment: I got the same issue in Windows 10 (on a mobile phone). The same call works on Android and Windows Phone 8 or 8.1. Wich plataform are you trying to launch the app via SMS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working for me fine. Just put the raw URI in the SMS.

`myapp:param=test`

This should show as a link in the SMS which when clicked will launch the app or cause the Store app to open.

Of course on a phone which doesn't support the URI this won't work. An alternative would be to send by SMS a link to a website which then presents a app-launch link on compatible phones. (This is what Spotify does for example).

Comment: Very strange, it does not work for me. Neither `myapp:param=test` nor `myapp://param:test` appear clickable. The way through a website would be my last resort. However, I can't believe that this is not possible by using solely Short Messages.

Comment: Yes I see that too. However `spotify:user:optop:playlist:1rZzpw4odSjn6z7YA3sSsa` is clickable.

Comment: Hmm, not even that is clickable for me. I am starting to think that it might be related to the country of the phone (it would not be the first time that countries in Europe cannot use specific features). It seems, I really have to go the way through the website. :/

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Nokia Developer page](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/URI_associations_for_Windows_Phone). The pattern for the Uri association is following:

```
<Custom Protocol Name>:<LandingPage>?[NavigationParameter1]=[NavigationValue1]
```

Where expressions in square brackets are optional. It means that you have to specify application name and a Landing page, which you want to reach. Example: `myapp:MainPage`, navigation parameters are optional. In WMAppManifest.xaml you will have something like this:

```
<Extensions>
  <Protocol Name="myApp" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default"/>
</Extensions>
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Tryied it now and realized, that the association does not work with dash in protocol name.