# Launch application automatically from an SMS on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I would like to launch an application using parameters provided from an SMS. 
The behaviour I wish to achieve is that as soon as the user receives an SMS, the application will be launched with the parameters provided in the SMS. I.e. seamlessly present the SMS in a more user friendly way.

I have experimented with URI protocol associations and so far I can send an SMS to the test phone with text `unleashed:param=test` (protocol is taken from book “Windows Phone 8 Unleashed”, code is in `WP8UnleashedSource_01_05\Source\FileAndProtocolAssociations`).
When pressing the link in the received SMS the application is launched successfully.

But it would be great if the is a way to also launch the application automatically as soon as the SMS is received.

Is this possible on all Windows Phone models and versions from 8 and up? 
Or are there other approaches, for example use push notifications, that are better suited to achieve the seamless use-case I described?

Thanks & Regards

This question is similar to [Launch App through SMS (URI-Association)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244484/launch-app-through-sms-uri-association) but I would like to concentrate on the automatic launch.

Comment: It is not possible to intercept all text messages on the phone. As a security feature, I shouldn't be able to send an untrusted text message which causes your phone to take an action in an application. Yes, a push notification for your app would be far better.

Comment: Thanks Václav! It may not be possible on Windows Phone but it is possible on Android by extending BroadcastReceiver, see (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435354/receiving-sms-on-android-app). Do you have any link for this information, in that case I can close the question with a no.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 8 support to capture SMS or a incoming call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176545/windows-phone-8-support-to-capture-sms-or-a-incoming-call)

Comment: Thanks I missed that thread! According to Claus MSFT reply it is not possible for normal developers, nor will it be on Windows Phone 8.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible on the Windows Phone 8 due to some security reasons.

This might be possible in Windows Phone 8.1. I read somewhere that 8.1 supports 3rd party SMS clients. This might mean there may some event that fires when new SMS are received. I am not sure though.

I would still suggest you to use Push Notifications.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But is it really possible to launch an application using push notifications?

As I understood there are three options: Toast, Tile and Raw.

RAW seems to require that the application already is started (did I miss something here, otherwise the use of raw seems a bit limited)

Toast doesn't start the application unless I press the Toast when it is displayed.

Tiles could work, it doesn't start the application but it can show the required information. The downside is that it has to be quite high up in among the tiles to be noticed.

Comment: @hirro All you said is correct. So yes there is no way to open app unless the user wants it to