# Launch application automatically from a push notification on Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone, windows-10-mobile

This is a reboot of question [Launch application automatically from a push notification on Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23628292/launch-application-automatically-from-a-push-notification-on-windows-phone-8) but for Windows 10 Mobile.

Is there any positive development on this in Windows 10 Mobile?

Comment: Do you want to lanuch an application without even user interaction on push?

Comment: Exactly, need to decrypt the payload of the push message (which I, on success, want to display to the user).

Answer (score 2):

It's basically the same as on Windows Phone 8.1.

You cannot directly launch an app into the foreground on receiving a push notification, but you can trigger a background task by push notification. The task can then decrypt the payload and fire a toast and tile notification to display it to the user. For a long message the toast can let the user launch the app to view the full message.

See [Background tasks triggered by raw notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt187200.aspx#bg_tasks) in MSDN.

The [Raw notifications sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Raw-notifications-sample-3bc28c5d#content) demonstrates this for Windows and Windows Phone 8.1.